# Scan to Ubuntu Folder using Brother ADS-1700W Network Scan

Tags: networking, scanner, brother

I am trying to scan to a specific folder in /home/bob/paperless-ngx/consume from my brother network scanner ADS-1700W.

I have installed the drivers, I can scan a document using SimpleScan, I can Ping the scanner from terminal.

However, if I set the Network Folder Path on the Network scanner, it does not work, and I get a Server timeout every time.

Can someone help?

Best,
Bob

Comment: missing things: on what filesystem are and who owns paperless-ngx and consume?

Comment: Of course: I am running this on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I own paperless and consume. I can access from other computers in the network via ssh.